# what does "On Your Network" in React mean

Tags: reactjs, npm

What does "On Your Network" mean when I run npm start in a React Project
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaTVk.png)

what does On Your Network:  http://192.168.56.1:3000 mean

Answer (score 2):

"On your network" in this context means from another computer that's connected to the same network (eg. the same Wifi network). You could browse your locally-hosted React app from your phone, for example. That IP address is your computer's local IP address (which is different from your public IP address).

Answer (score 0):

"on your network" means that on your local network like your wifi you can access your web page in your local network (that can be your phone or any computer or internet enabled device on your wifi) with that ip address. just type http://192.168.56.1:3000 in your browser.